# Error Message when using Query(import in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using this very long formula and I keep getting In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows message. I have used this formula before with just a few tweeks on this one and it has worked. Any ideas on what I am missing?

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CxWKZqOS1nSP2dsvYJc6JPx58976UDzN6kk0t8OJXCY/edit#gid=0","ABC!A2:EB"); IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IpTw9XuNPbObRahfT1QHaNYlJW9IaUGMxziflKVoXkw/edit#gid=565472041","ABC!A2:EB"); IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IMutqQOxIKfwabbJLhnEeXdSANyVpKpFN-VMqTSfFp4/edit#gid=0","ABC!A2:EB"); IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wDgPcGXO2_UXFt8T2c4yHmV_1qOptQDKYEuszEOM6QM/edit#gid=1657992909","ABC!A2:EB");  IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BjuK3NTrXfnSsuE-zsXBmZ3WWilVYQm1fJwPlKkY61U/edit#gid=2018775119","ABC!A2:EB")}, "Select * WHERE Col1 is not null"))`

I have done done it with 2 links and it works but anytime I add a third or more I get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

*Try replacing this part of the formula:*

```js
{
 <importrange_1>;
 <importrange_2>;
 <importrange_3>;
 <importrange_4>;
 <importrange_5>
}
```

*with*

```js
 ifna(vstack(
             <importrange_1>,
             <importrange_2>,
             <importrange_3>,
             <importrange_4>,
             <importrange_5>
      ))
```

*& test*

- *this suggestion is based on an assumption that one or more of your importrange data(s) could be blank maybe (null data) & the particular stacking you used via., braces `{` `}` will throw an error in such a scenario while the suggested `ifna + vstack` will be able to handle such a scenario*

---

*Also make sure to test each `importrange()` separately just to make sure they are linked perfect & is pullin' in data right...*

Comment: This answer would be more helpful to others, if you explained the reason behind your suggestion.